# Calling a model's method from another model

Tags: django, django-models

I am quite new to `django` so my question might seem very trivial..
I have 2 models (simplified for demonstration purposes):

```
class Subarticle(models.Model):
    parent_article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='subarticles')
    priority = IntegerField()
    ....
    def getCheapest(self, quantity): //find cheapest subarticle based on qty
        //code
```

and

```
class Article(models.Model):
    sub_article_qty = models.IntegerField()
    def production_cost(self):
       sub_article = Subarticle.objects.filter(parent_article=self).order_by('priority').first 
       sub_article_price = sub_article.getCheapest(self.sub_article_qty)
       return sub_article_price*self.sub_article_qty
```

So basically every article has one or more sub-articles and I want to be able to find the cost for the article based on the cheapest priced sub-article with the lowest priority number.

I am using "`rest_framwork`" to send the model data with approximately following `serializer`

```
from .models import Subarticles, Articles
from rest_framwork import serializers

class SubarticleSerializer(serializer.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model=Subarticle
         fields=('parent_article','priority')

class ArticleSerializer(serializer.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model=Article
         fields=('sub_article_qty','subarticles','production_cost')
```

But trying to do this like this gives me the following error:

```
Exception raised in callable attribute "production_cost"; original exception was: 'function' object has no attribute 'getCheapest'
```

Is it even possible to do it as I am trying to do or is there some other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

`first` is a method; you didn't call it.

```
sub_article = Subarticle.objects.filter(parent_article=self).order_by('priority').first()
```

Note, an easier way of spelling this is:

```
sub_article = self.subarticles.all().order_by('priority').first()
```